# Government procurement bids

Tags: data-request, usa, government, spending, fbo.gov

The US federal government publishes contracts on [USASpending.gov](https://www.usaspending.gov/Pages/Default.aspx) and RFPs on [FBO.gov](https://www.fbo.gov/?s=main&mode=list&tab=list).

Contracts contain extensive description of the vendor. But I haven't find the similarly detailed data on RFP results. Namely, for competitive purchases (like those on FBO.gov):

- DUNS number of each bidder
- Region, revenue, and number of employees of the bidder
- Price offered by the bidder
- Status (minority-, woman-, veteran-owned)

FBO.gov requires a login to view the list of interested vendors (eg [this RFP](https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=form&id=fa41728e491fee7030dbb7a166b46810&tab=ivl&tabmode=list)). But it does not seem machine-readable anyway.

I haven't found it on Data.gov either.

Is this information available or bidding data is closed?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not usually made public but I have heard of success FOIA'ing for specific opportunities that were competitively bid.